# $D_n = \{x\in\mathbb R: F(x) - F(x^-) \ge 1/n\}$ is finite for $n\in\mathbb N$ if $F$ is a distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $D$ be the set of discontinuity points of a distribution function $F$. $D_n = \{x\in\mathbb R: F(x) - F(x^-) \ge 1/n\}$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. Show that each $D_n$ is finite. Hence, show that a distribution function cannot have an uncountable number of discontinuities.

So, I know that a distribution function $F$ must be such that:

1. $F$ is an increasing function on $\mathbb R$.
2. $\lim_{t\to\infty} F(t) = 1$ and $\lim_{t\to -\infty} F(t) = 0$
3. $F$ is right continuous.
4. If $F$ has no jump discontinuities in $[a,b]$, then $F(a) = F(b)$.

How do I show the required statement now? I am trying to construct a proof by contradiction. Suppose $D_m$ is not finite for some $m\in\mathbb N$. **What now?**

I was able to do the second part of the proof anyway, i.e. if the $D_n$'s are all finite then $D$ is countable. Here's how: $$D = \{a\in\mathbb R: F(a) - F(a^-) > 0\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n$$

**Assuming** that all $D_n$'s are finite, hence countable - we see that $D$ is countable (a countable union of countable sets is countable).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can actually bound the cardinality of $D_n$ by $n$ itself. Indeed, suppose that $x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}$ are distinct elements in $D_n$ listed in an increasing order.

Then, $f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i) \ge 1/n$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$. (We are only using monotonicity here to note that $f(x_{i+1}^-) \ge f(x_i)$.)

Adding the equations for all $i$ together gives us that $$f(x_{n+1}) - f(x_1) \ge \dfrac{n + 1}{n} > 1.$$
However, this contradicts that the image of $f$ is contained in $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 3):

If $D_m$ is infinite for some $m$ your function would jump up by at least $1/m$ infinitely many times so it would increase to infinity, violating the fact that the limit at infinity is $1$.